# Scroll the div till the last div on mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll4

Another question on [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). I have set up a [demo in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugeU3/).

I want to scroll the `div` on `mousedown`. It should scroll to the end:

- continuously;
- without any interruption;
- with static speed;

Until it reaches the last `div`, or I do a `mouseup` in the middle.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2YWZ/2/

There is still one problem. It doesn't stop when it reaches the end. iScroll uses CSS `translate` to do the scrolling and I couldn't find a way to get the current translation form it. Currently looking for a solution for that.

**UPDATE**

iScroll has a useTransform option, using which we can ask it not use translate and instead use CSS left property for scrolling. This way we'll be easily able to identify whether its the end has been reached (either way). To use, simply set `useTransform: false` while initing iScroll.

**UPDATE 2**

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2YWZ/12/

Comment: I have checked the demo you did. It is working pretty good except the point you mentioned and also one thing that i noticed is on mousedown it is doing its job but on immediate click and leave (single click) there is something that needs to be done so that only one div moves in or out. I have a fixed div width. So can you look into that working once. Here something unusual is happening on single click.

Comment: If you look at the iscroll source code, you will see there is a `useTransform` option, using which you can ask it not use translate and instead use CSS left property for scrolling. This way we'll be easily able to identify whether its the end has been reached (either way).

Comment: I tried the method you suggested. Is there a way to get the current left position in the move function of iscroll4 during scrolling. At the end we can get the left value but while scrolling how to understand that the scroller has reached the end and it should be stopped until we get the left value of scroll in the move function of iscroll.

Comment: Added a fiddle demonstrating the `useTransform: false` approach

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this solution: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/ugeU3/3](http://jsfiddle.net/ugeU3/3/)

html:

```
<div id="click">Element to click on</div>
```

js:

```
jQuery("#click").bind('mousedown', function(){
    intInterval=setInterval(function(){
            myScroll.scrollTo(25, 0, 800, true);
    },30);
});
jQuery("#click").bind('mouseup', function(){
    intInterval=window.clearInterval(intInterval);
});
```

you can change the time values to achieve your speed-preferences.
i hope it helps.

Comment: Well, even this one has the problem i mentioned i my answer (doesn't stop at the end). Also, since the mouse up is handled by the trigger element itself, if user moves the mouse away by mistake, scroll cannot be stopped after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified **@techfoobar** code and done something like this which both scrolls continously till end on mousedown and moves one div in or out on single click. The code snippet is :

```
        var scrolling=false;
        var scrollTimer=-1;
        $('#next').bind('mousedown',function () {
            scrolling = true;
            scrollTimer = setInterval(function () {
                scrollDivRight();
            }, 100);
            return false;
        });
        $('#next').bind('mouseup',function () {
            scrolling = false;
            clearInterval(scrollTimer);
            return false;
        });
        $('#next').bind('mouseout',function () { /*For smoother effect and also prevent if any previous delay (eg. 100ms)*/
            scrolling = false;
            clearInterval(scrollTimer);
            return false;
        });
        scrollDivRight:function(){
            if(!scrolling) return false;
            myScroll.scrollTo(177, 0, 400, true);       
        }
```

Please suggest if there is anything better then this. Ofcourse the issue mentioned by **@techfoobar** in his answer still remains unsolved.